# OpenCV Qt Setup with MS Visual C++ 2012 Compiler

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, compilation

Like the title says, I have been using Qt creator along with a kit that uses the Visual C++ 12.0 (x86_amd64) compiler and I have been trying to get openCV set up so that I can use that library in my project.  I downloaded the most recent version of openCV (alpha 3.0.0) and have tried numerous ways of trying to link it to QT, but no matter what I try it fails.
I have tried looking at several tutorials that have been using Cmake to compile the source into binaries, but those have also failed.  Since I am using the C++ 12 compiler, is it possible to just use the pre-compiled binaries that come with the download, or do I have to manually compile them?  I downloaded it from the OpenCV site and tried to use cmake to compile the binaries, configured with the visual C++ 2012 compiler, but I have no idea where to go after those binaries are generated so that's why I have tried with the binaries you download straight from the site.
Any thoughts or links to tutorials are greatly appreciated, I just can't get this thing to work.
A few things I have tried have been adding

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\sources\include"
```

To link to cv.h, and I have these libraries linked because I tried linking all the ones I found in the pre compiled binaries

```
LIBS += "C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ts300.lib"
    "C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ts300d.lib"
    "C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_world300.lib"
    "C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_world300d.lib"
```

Comment: You have to provide more information, the code that you have tried as well as the location where you downloaded it from, how it was built, etc.

Comment: please use *only* debug libs for a debug build, and *only* release libs for a release build, not both.